# Supports (register_post_type) doesn't remove Comments?

Tags: wordpress

I've created multiple post types, and `support` works fine, except it doesn't seem to affect the **Discussion** or **Comments** metaboxes.

When I write this...

```
'supports' => array('title')
```

...it removes everything except the title, like it should, but Discussions and Comments are still there. What gives?

*Update: `remove_post_type_support('example_post_type','comments');` does remove Comments. Still not sure why `supports` doesn't do the job when registering the post type.